# Disadvantages of SIM vs TIC in GC-MS

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography, mass-spectrometry

In GC-MS what are the relative advantages/disadvantages of using Selected-Ion Monitoring (SIM) vs using Total Ion Chromatograms (TIC)?

I know that SIM offers a better S/N ratio, however if the S/N is acceptable using TIC, is it better to use TIC and if so, why?

Comment: I think you should search *why* and *when* SIM is used? Hints: What do you think if peak overlap in a chromatogram? Will TIC be able to identify what compounds are eluting underneath?

Comment: But if there is no overlap using TIC and the peaks are all seen clearly, separately and with little noise using TIC, is their any advantage of using SIM?

Comment: If you are 100% sure that there is no overlap, then there is no harm in using TIC. SIM could be used for confirmation.